# SQL Server Alias stopped working

Tags: sql-server, alias

I have configured a SQL Server 2016 alias following [this post](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/02/09/how-to-configure-a-sql-server-alias-for-a-named-instance-on-a-development-machine) and it was working, but suddenly it stopped working.

Error message:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

I created the alias using the SQL Server Configuration Manager and created it in the 32 and 64bit:

[image]

When I go to the `Protocols` for SQL Server Express, all of them are enabled, thus TCP/IP is enabled. Also, the SQL Server Browser service is running.

Looking at the system log there is no relevant message about it, so I'm a bit lost about what could be causing it to stop working. My OS is Windows 10 Pro.

Would you have any clues to help me solve it? Thanks for any help

Comment: Define "it stopped working". The alias probably didn't stop working, but whatever is supposed to rely on the alias might have. Check what `sqlcmd -S "NGAGE-S-001" -Q "SELECT @@SERVERNAME"` returns to verify the alias is still aliasing.

Comment: This also happened to me after I uninstalled Sql 2014 while having 2016 installed. sqlcmd.exe doesn't seem to find the defined aliases although other programs do, such as SSMS and Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the SQLEXPRESS instance's port number hasn't changed, which is likely after a reboot or service restart.

Regarding the use of instance aliases, this is pretty much useless if you're also using dynamic ports for this very reason. To me it's more cumbersome to maintain this configuration than it is to maintain a connection string in your program IMHO.